# Erro ao copiar dados de uma tabela para outra

Tags: java, sql, query

Boa tarde Pessoal, estou fazendo uma aplicação que faz uma solicitação de empréstimo de dvs, eu consegui fazer a aplicação para inserir a reserva, agora preciso fazer que o dono do dvd confirme o aluguel e copie os dados na tabela de dvd alugados mas eu não tenho nem ideia se esta certo, porque só sai erro quando eu tento copiar os dados para tabela de alugados.

Aqui eu solicitei o emprestimo e esta funcionando:

public class SolicitarEmprestimoDAO {

```
private static String horaPedido;

private static String dataPedido;

public void solicitarEmprestimo(ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo e) throws SQLException{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("INSERT INTO solicitacaoemprestimo ");
    sql.append("(dataemprestimo,horaemprestimo,  codigo_socio_solicitou_emprestimo, dvd_codigo, socio_codigo) ");
    sql.append("VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

    Connection conexao = FabricaDeConexao.conectar();
    PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

    comando.setString(1, e.solicitarDataPedido());
    comando.setString(2, e.solicitarHoraPedido());
    comando.setLong(3, e.getCodigoSocioSolicitouEmprestimo());
    comando.setLong(4, e.getDvd().getCodigo());
    comando.setLong(5, e.getSocio().getCodigo());

    comando.executeUpdate();


}

public List<ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo> selicionarPedidosDeEmprestimo(ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo clube) throws SQLException{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("SELECT codemprestimo, dataemprestimo, horaemprestimo, codigo_socio_solicitou_emprestimo, dvd_codigo, socio_codigo ");
    sql.append("FROM solicitacaoemprestimo ");
    sql.append("WHERE socio_codigo = ? ");
    sql.append("ORDER BY dataemprestimo ASC, horaemprestimo ASC ");

    Connection conexao = FabricaDeConexao.conectar();

    PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
    comando.setLong(1, clube.getSocio().getCodigo());

    ResultSet resultado = comando.executeQuery();

    List<ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo> retorno = new ArrayList<>();

    while(resultado.next()){

        final ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo cdpe = new ClubeDoDvdPedidoEmprestimo();
        cdpe.setCodEmprestimo((resultado.getLong("codemprestimo")));
        cdpe.setDataPedido(resultado.getString("dataemprestimo"));
        cdpe.setHoraPedido(resultado.getString("horaemprestimo"));
        cdpe.setCodigoSocioSolicitouEmprestimo(resultado.getLong("codigo_socio_solicitou_emprestimo"));
        Socio s = new Socio();
        s.setCodigo(resultado.getLong("socio_codigo"));
        cdpe.setSocio(s);

        Dvd d = new Dvd();
        d.setCodigo(resultado.getLong("dvd_codigo"));
        cdpe.setDvd(d);

        retorno.add(cdpe);
    }
    return retorno;

}
```

Aqui tentei fazer os dados da tabela de solicitação de empréstimo irem para tabela de dvds alugado:

public class DvdAlugadoDAO {

```
public void dvdAlugados(Alugados e) throws SQLException{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("INSERT INTO alugados (dataemprestimo, horaemprestimo, solicitacaoemprestimo_codemprestimo, solicitacaoemprestimo_dvd_codigo, solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo) ");
    sql.append("SELECT dataemprestimo, horaemprestimo, codemprestimo ,dvd_codigo, socio_codigo ");
    sql.append("FROM solicitacaoemprestimo ");
    sql.append(" WHERE codemprestimo = ? ");

    Connection conexao = FabricaDeConexao.conectar();
    PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

    comando.setLong(1, e.getClubeDoDvdEmprestimo().getCodEmprestimo());
    comando.setString(2, e.getDataEmprestimo());
    comando.setString(3, e.getHoraEprestimo());
    comando.setLong(4, e.getClubeDoDvdEmprestimo().getCodEmprestimo());
    comando.setLong(5, e.getClubeDoDvdEmprestimo().getDvd().getCodigo());
    comando.setLong(6, e.getClubeDoDvdEmprestimo().getSocio().getCodigo());

    comando.executeUpdate();

}
```

Comment: Quando for assim, tenta postar os StackTrace da exessão que ocorre tb.

Answer (score 0):

Seu SQL no método "dvdAlugados" pede apenas que você forneça o código do empréstimo (codemprestimo):

```
sql.append("INSERT INTO alugados (dataemprestimo, horaemprestimo, solicitacaoemprestimo_codemprestimo, solicitacaoemprestimo_dvd_codigo, solicitacaoemprestimo_socio_codigo) ");
sql.append("SELECT dataemprestimo, horaemprestimo, codemprestimo ,dvd_codigo, socio_codigo ");
sql.append("FROM solicitacaoemprestimo ");
sql.append(" WHERE codemprestimo = ? ");
```

Porém você está tentando associar outros 5 parâmetros que não são necessários e devem ser removidos:

```
comando.setLong(1, e.getClubeDoDvdEmprestimo().getCodEmprestimo());
//comando.setString(2, e.getDataEmprestimo());
//comando.setString(3, e.getHoraEprestimo());
//comando.setLong(4, e.getClubeDoDvdEmprestimo().getCodEmprestimo());
//comando.setLong(5, e.getClubeDoDvdEmprestimo().getDvd().getCodigo());
//comando.setLong(6, e.getClubeDoDvdEmprestimo().getSocio().getCodigo());
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo.... Valeu Parceiro...